# Pandas: Get Rows in 1st dataframe with same values (in two columns) in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've two data frames `A and B` with columns `col1, col2, col3`.

I want to get all rows in A having same values in column `col2, col3` of `A AND B`.

> P.S. The index of rows in A and B having same values in col2 and col3 are not necessarily same.

Comment: Can you provide an example with your desired output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC you can try [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html):

```
print A
  col1 col2 col3
0   aa    1    2
1   bb    2    5

print B
  col1 col2 col3
0   aa    1    2
1   aa    1    3
2   bb    2    5

print pd.merge(A,B, on=['col1','col2','col3'], how='left')
  col1 col2 col3
0   aa    1    2
1   bb    2    5
```